# How to print just first name instead of full using beautiful soup python

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, webdriver

Hi I want to know about how i can print the the first name instead of full here is the code I'm trying using selenium python

```
<strong class="pillow-name">Nano Tech</strong>
```

I just want to print the first name that is "Nano" using BS4 and selenium..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
pillowName = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".pillow-name").text
firstWord = pillowName.split()[0]
```